# Using Relative Layout to create horizontal search bar results in UI elements disappearing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm experiencing an issue where all the items in my XML UI layout are disappearing after adding/implementing a horizontal search bar.

Before adding it - my layout looked fine - so I'm unsure why everything disappeared.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

### Source (XML):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ListView_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/searchbar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/searchbartxtcontainer"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Search " />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ListView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.7" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2a"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dialogTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/OkButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch1"
            android:text="Questions: Enables the display of trivia questions" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/switch2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/switch2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch2"
            android:text="Write-Up: Enables the display of trivia factoids." />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/switch3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/switch3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch3"
            android:text="Polls: Mixes polls in the sequence of trivia questions." />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/OkButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="300dp" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/OkButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="250dp" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/OkButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/switch4"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/switch4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch4"
            android:text="One-Try: Correct answer identified after first attempt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/switch5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/switch5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch5"
            android:text="Multi-Try: Correct answer identified after first attempt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/switch6"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/switch6"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch5"
            android:text="Fast-Try: Points awarded based on answer speed" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/switch4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/OkButton"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/t"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/switch5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/OkButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/switch6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/OkButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/triviaSettingsTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Trivia Settings"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/triviaPlayModes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/triviaSettingsTitle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Trivia Play Modes"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W477m.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave a width of the layout to be 0dp

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
```

change this to

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
```

Hope this helps

and the weight is for LinearLayouts..... but u have used them in Relative Layouts and u have made similar mistakes in others elements too

Comment: Much appreciated... (Also - I went ahead and removed any references to weight - if you don't mind - can you point out the other mistake[s] you noticed? I'd like to learn from your experience - and I'm sure others could as well.)

Comment: u gave 0dp to `rl_ListView1` too... that is what i mentioned above